# 12 volt switched by 5 volt

Tags: transistors, switches, relay, 12v, 5v

I have an issue with 12 volt DC LEDs installed on a 5 volt DC circuit. Switching must be performed as close to instantaneous as possible.

So I searched around but nothing would do what I need. I found npn transistor and MOSFET switches for 12 v using a 5 v base\gate but these solutions modified the ground from the LED instead of the +12 circuit. My problem is I do not have access to the ground side. I must modify the 12 vdc circuit in order to achieve my goal. Am I limited to Solid State Relays or can this be achieved another way?

Hopefully this makes enough sense for someone to help me.

Comment: Frankly, it would make more sense if you add a circuit of what you want to implement.

Comment: What current will the LEDs take from 12V in total?

Answer (score 1):

NPN or Logic Level N-Channel mosfet as a driver for a PNP transistor/P-Channel Mosfet, which controls the High side of the leds.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQoxxo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. Your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

"High-side switching" is the term you are looking for. Typically, this involves P-channel MOSFETS, although it can be done with N-channel MOSFETs as well.

If you use a PMOS, then you can switch it easily from your 5V signal. However, an NMOS will require a boost circuit, as the gate voltage needs to exceed your supply voltage. Hence, a PMOS circuit (like the one in Passerby's excellent answer) is far more common and easier to build.

Also,

> as close to instantaneous as possible.

is meaningless, and you should provide actual constraints or context. Just because there exist semiconductor switches built of exotic materials with switching times in the picoseconds, does not mean you want those. A more realistic constraint would be appropriate.